# Google Cloud/GCP - Find all Ephemeral external IP addresses in use by GCP instrances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

One of our admins seems to have forgotten to disable the ephemeral external IP on some new systems that were built over the last year.  Unfortunately I'm not seeing a "friendly" way in the GCP GUI to locate all ephemeral IPs that are currently in use by our instances.

I'm looking for a way (GUI or gcloud commands) to find all external ephemeral IPs in use on a project.

Anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was incorrect.  In GCP "VPC Network > External IP Addresses" does indeed show ephemeral IPs now.

So problem (which turned out to not really be a problem) solved!